# css mega menu with animation

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a menu with a mega menu option.
The top level links have an underline animation.
If the top level nav has a mega class, the mega menu container shows, but the underline animation does not.

If I lower the mega menu container, the animation does show, but as soon as the mouse moves off the top link into the container, the container hides as there is a gap because the un-hover switches it off.

Also, moving right from the top level from Option1 to Option 2, nav hides the mega container and the animation shows(correct), but moving right to the Sign In link does not hide the mega container or do the animation.

```css
body #mainMenu {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#menuOptions {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#menuOptions li {
  display: flex;
}

#menuOptions li a {
  color: #000;
}

#menuOptions li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hover-underline-animation {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #0087ca;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hover-underline-animation:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.mega-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mega:hover .mega-container {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.mega-menu {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mega Menu</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <nav id='mainMenu'>
    <ul id='menuOptions'>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Sign In</a></li>
      <li class='mega'><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 1</a>
        <div class='mega-container'>
          <div class='mega-menu'>
            <p>This is mega menu 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 4</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 5</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='menuTopLevelItem hover-underline-animation'>Option 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code for animation with mega menu using css only.

1. set column in menu using float and width property of css or you can use table also.
2. you can use font.awesome style or html entity for icon of submenu.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Mega Menu</h4>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```